# Getting this error when trying to create new notebook in jupyter notebook

Tags: windows-10, python3, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The Error:= 
**"Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb attempt to write a readonly database."**

It is happening on windows10 machine, initially all is working fine but after install-uninstall(python3(32-bit) to python2 to python3(64-bit)) for couple of times, it is giving the weird error as mentioned, looked many answers saying the access issue, tried that too not working.

TIA